# Implement the functions using map and foldr, haskell

Tags: function, haskell, boolean, fold

I have two functions. The first one gives true if all elements of the list are zero

```
allZero :: [Int] -> Bool
allZero [] = False
allZero [0] = True
allZero (x:xs)
  | x == 0 && allZero xs = True
  |otherwise = False
```

The second function gives true if at least one element of the list is zero

```
oneZero :: [Int] -> Bool
oneZero [] = False
oneZero (x:xs)
   | x == 0 = True
   | otherwise = oneZero xs
```

Maybe there is another way to solve this problems. For example with map or foldr?
Thank you

Comment: What did you try? Can you implement `any` and `all` in terms of `foldr`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't quite understand how foldr works. I understand how map works, but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: `allZero [] = False` is surprising. Are you sure you don't want `True` in that case, as your informal specification implies?

Comment: what the above comment by chi implies is that allZero can be seen as noNonZeros and there are certainly no zeroes in [], so it should return True then. and that's the usual thing to do.

Comment: `allZero (x:xs) = x == 0 && allZero xs`. `oneZero (x:xs) = x == 0 || oneZero xs`. `allZero = all . map (== 0)`. `oneZero = any . map (== 0)`. `all == foldr (&&) True`. `any == foldr (||) False`. <meta> (this is not a full answer as it has no words in it, hence it is left as a comment.) </meta>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foldr` function works so:

Suppose, you have list `[1, 2, 3]`. Let's write this list as `(:) 1 ((:) 2 ((:) 3 []))`, where each element has type `a`. Function `foldr` takes function `f` of `a -> b -> b` type and starting element `z` of `b` type, and just replace `[]` to `z` and `:` to `f`. So, `foldr f z ((:) 1 ((:) 2 ((:) 3 []))) == f 1 (f 2 (f 3 z))`.

So, you can define your functions so:

```hs
allZero = foldr (\x -> x == 0 &&) True

oneZero = foldr (\x -> x == 0 ||) False
```

Comment: `> :t foldr (\x -> x == 0 &&) True` gives an error. :)

Answer (score 0):

`foldr` basically takes your guard as its folding function:

```
allZero = foldr (\x acc -> x == 0 && acc) True
```

`acc` (for **acc**umulator) is the already-computed value of the recursive call. Being right-associative, the first non-zero value in the list short-circuits the evaluation of the fold function on the rest of the list.

(Note that `allZero [] == True` by convention. The "hypothesis" is that `allZero xs` is true, with evidence in the form of a non-zero element to falsify the hypothesis. No elements in the list, no evidence to contradict the hypothesis.)

I leave it as an exercise to adapt this to compute `oneZero`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a "convention". It's a necessary conclusion of some obviously useful properties we want our logic to have: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426051/hows-it-possible-for-each-element-of-the-empty-set-to-be-even.

Comment: re "convention", it's a consequence of  `allZeroes (a ++ b) = allZeroes a && allZeroes b` thus `allZeroes a = allZeroes (a ++ []) = allZeroes a && allZeroes []`, and `True` being `&&`'s identity element. (also, if it's already computed, there's no short-circuiting. :) )

Comment: I'd argue that `allZeros` is a homomorphism *because* `allZeroes []` is defined to be `True`, not the other way around, but yes, "convention" isn't the best way to put this.